# How to make integer scale in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to make a horizontal bar chart with an integer scale.
As suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514984/javascript-chart-js-scale-fix/36319934#36319934), I've tried to set `scaleOverride`, `scaleSteps` etc, but it seems not to be working. I tried to put them in dataset, in options, in xScales but nothing worked.

[This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djf4gg1m/) shows what I tried to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The linked question is for Chart.js version 1.x. For the new version you need to use the `ticks` option. See http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales

```
   ...
   xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        min: 0,
        stepSize: 1,
        max: 4
      },
      ...
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jkufz1b9/

Comment: Can you please refer to the version 1.x 's documentation as well.

Comment: The new documentation version: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration-options (search for "stepSize" to find all the occurrences, if you are looking for another chart type)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this nowadays (ChartJS 4+), if you want to keep the automatic `stepSize` and **not** define it statically, you can simply use the `precision` option on the ticks to define to how many decimal places the ticks will be rounded. Use `0` for an integer scale:

```json
scales: {
  y: {
    ticks: { precision: 0 },
  },
}
```

[Linear Axis Tick Options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-axis-specific-tick-options)