# Chart Js change y axis to real number

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am using latest chart js and i want to change Y axis value to real number 
0,1,2,3,....
[image]

i want to change y axis in to positive real numbers where do i put scales value to change above format to real number format

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");


            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: allDate,
                    datasets:jsonArray,
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            display:true
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            display:true,
                            type: "linear",
                            ticks: {
                                userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
                                    return value;
                                }
                            } 
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make integer scale in Chartjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287641/how-to-make-integer-scale-in-chartjs)