# chatjs >=2.0 how do i eliminate decimals in the yaxis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

As the title says, with the new configuration method in 2.0, how do i remove decimals from the yaxis in the options?

```
data: { 
 datasets: [{

 }],
 options: {
}
```

Comment: `Math.round(decimalValue)` use this to remove decimal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make integer scale in Chartjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287641/how-to-make-integer-scale-in-chartjs)