# Two vertical lines in chart - chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

[image]

I am using chart and it is working fine too , I followed [Chart Docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) to understand how chart working but I am seeing two lines in chart , I was expecting only one line for y-axis , I have posted my entire code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286574/how-can-configure-my-y-axis-on-chart-js) post , please find read one which marked as answer.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with highcharts? In general it looks like you have 2 xAxis but without seeing code not sure.

Comment: Thank for reply... I have given a link where I have posted my entire code , please click on "this" on above post it will redirect you to another thread of stackoverflow, I dont want to duplicate code paste that why I have provided link.

Comment: Hi, I put your previous data here, the chart working fine. http://jsbin.com/jixiza/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi Nasir, good catch I am not sure why it is not working with this sample data  var sample1 ={
 labels:["Thu 05-12","Fri 05-13","Sat 05-14","Sun 05-15","Mon 05-16","Tue 05-17","Wed 05-18","Thu 05-19","Fri 05-20","Sat 05-21","Sun 05-22","Mon 05-23","Tue 05-24","Wed 05-25"],
 datasets:[{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        backgroundColor: "red",
        data: [9, 6, 6, 8, 6, 9, 8]
    },
 {
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        backgroundColor: "rgba(225,226,228,0.5)",
        data: [9, 6, 6, 8, 6, 9, 8]
    }]
 
};